# Can WinObjC apps run on iPhones?

Tags: winobjc

I know that this is *really* basic, but since this is a new tag and technology, I hope you'll permit the question.

Having just discovered the existence of [WinObjC](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC) (the Windows Bridge for iOS project) I want to understand what I can do with this before I start to devote time to it.

The following project description is a little confusing to me:

> The Windows Bridge for iOS (also referred to as WinObjC) is a
>   Microsoft open-source project that provides an Objective-C development
>   environment for Visual Studio and support for iOS APIs. The bridge
>   allows you to create Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps that will
>   run on many Windows devices using iOS APIs and Objective-C code
>   alongside Windows 10 features like Cortana and Live Tiles.

I mean, I see it says ***for iOS*** but OTOH it says that it allows you to create UWP apps that run ***on many Windows devices***. I am embarrassed to say I find this confusing.

I feel 90% sure that it is not for developing iPhone apps, but a 10% chance I can develop for iPhone without being able to buy a new enough Macbook is enough to make me ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Bridge for iOS allows you to build UWP apps by reusing code you wrote for an iOS app. Say, for instance, you wrote an iPhone game; you could use the bridge to turn it into a UWP game that runs on Windows desktops, laptops and touch-screen devices. You could also use the bridge to add Windows-specific features like Live Tiles and Cortana integration.

If you'd like to develop for iOS without having to buy a new MacBook, you might want to check out another Microsoft project called [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com) which allows you to do cross-platform mobile development right from Visual Studio.

Comment: Great info, thanks. Yea I got started with Iconic and CODAPPS for hybrid development but I'm not too happy with them, so I will check out Xamarin.